# Detecting and counting when Pandas DataFrame with time-indexed float column exceeds a threshold for longer than 5-minutes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a simple DataFrame containing heart rate (and related columns), indexed by unique and monotonically increasing datetime values, sampled in one-minute intervals (with some breaks where the sensor was removed). Here is a sample:

```
print(data)
                               End Time    HR  Min HR  Max HR
Start Time                                                   
2020-10-14 18:27:00 2020-10-14 18:27:59  87.0    84.0    89.0
2020-10-14 18:28:00 2020-10-14 18:28:59  89.0    85.0    94.0
2020-10-14 18:29:00 2020-10-14 18:29:59  87.0    84.0    90.0
2020-10-14 18:30:00 2020-10-14 18:30:59  91.0    87.0    96.0
2020-10-14 18:31:00 2020-10-14 18:31:59  95.0    91.0   100.0
...                                 ...   ...     ...     ...
2021-07-08 22:26:00 2021-07-08 22:26:59  73.0    70.0    76.0
2021-07-08 22:27:00 2021-07-08 22:27:59  76.0    74.0    79.0
2021-07-08 22:28:00 2021-07-08 22:28:59  71.0    70.0    74.0
2021-07-08 22:29:00 2021-07-08 22:29:59  71.0    69.0    74.0
2021-07-08 22:30:00 2021-07-08 22:30:59  74.0    72.0    78.0

[373234 rows x 4 columns]
```

I want to detect 'peaks', which are defined as the heart rate going over the threshold for 5-minutes or more. So, to be clear, when a peak lasts 10-minutes, it's still one peak, not two.

Of course, I can filter by threshold:

```
maybe_peaks = data[data['HR']>= threshold])]
print(maybe_peaks)

                               End Time     HR  Min HR  Max HR
Start Time                                                    
2020-10-16 12:14:00 2020-10-16 12:14:59  104.0    95.0   108.0
2020-10-16 12:15:00 2020-10-16 12:15:59  111.0   106.0   115.0
2020-10-16 12:16:00 2020-10-16 12:16:59  132.0   105.0   157.0
2020-10-16 12:17:00 2020-10-16 12:17:59  126.0   106.0   159.0
2020-10-16 12:18:00 2020-10-16 12:18:59  109.0   108.0   111.0
...                                 ...    ...     ...     ...
2021-07-04 12:58:00 2021-07-04 12:58:59  103.0    97.0   116.0
2021-07-06 13:38:00 2021-07-06 13:38:59  106.0   103.0   108.0
2021-07-06 13:39:00 2021-07-06 13:39:59  104.0   102.0   109.0
2021-07-06 17:02:00 2021-07-06 17:02:59  121.0    98.0   135.0
2021-07-07 19:58:00 2021-07-07 19:58:59  110.0   105.0   116.0

[12940 rows x 4 columns]
```

But then the problem becomes: how do I further filter out rows where the time above threshold is shorter than 5-minutes.

Of course, I can do this C-style, looping row-by-row, but I feel that would be neither the most efficient nor elegant way.

Ultimately, I want to build a plot with calendar days on the *x*-axis and frequency/count of these peak events along *y*.

Any hints/direction would be appreciated.

Here is some sample data to help:

```
from pandas import Timestamp
test_dat = [[Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:00:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:00:59'), 99.0, 95.0, 105.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:01:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:01:59'), 96.0, 91.0, 102.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:02:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:02:59'), 100.0, 96.0, 105.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:03:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:03:59'), 96.0, 91.0, 100.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:04:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:04:59'), 93.0, 88.0, 102.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:05:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:05:59'), 105.0, 99.0, 110.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:06:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:06:59'), 102.0, 97.0, 109.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:07:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:07:59'), 96.0, 87.0, 102.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:08:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:08:59'), 96.0, 93.0, 101.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:09:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:09:59'), 96.0, 90.0, 106.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:10:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:10:59'), 100.0, 95.0, 110.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:11:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:11:59'), 100.0, 95.0, 113.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:12:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:12:59'), 98.0, 91.0, 103.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:13:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:13:59'), 101.0, 97.0, 108.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:14:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:14:59'), 98.0, 91.0, 102.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:15:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:15:59'), 100.0, 93.0, 110.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:16:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:16:59'), 96.0, 89.0, 104.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:17:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:17:59'), 98.0, 95.0, 104.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:18:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:18:59'), 95.0, 93.0, 99.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:19:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:19:59'), 94.0, 84.0, 104.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:20:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:20:59'), 94.0, 90.0, 99.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:21:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:21:59'), 98.0, 95.0, 100.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:22:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:22:59'), 98.0, 97.0, 102.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:23:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:23:59'), 98.0, 96.0, 102.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:24:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:24:59'), 98.0, 96.0, 100.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:25:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:25:59'), 96.0, 95.0, 100.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:26:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:26:59'), 102.0, 98.0, 105.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:27:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:27:59'), 97.0, 92.0, 103.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:28:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:28:59'), 92.0, 87.0, 99.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:29:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:29:59'), 96.0, 94.0, 99.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:30:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:30:59'), 97.0, 93.0, 100.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:31:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:31:59'), 101.0, 97.0, 103.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:32:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:32:59'), 99.0, 95.0, 103.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:33:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:33:59'), 101.0, 93.0, 105.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:34:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:34:59'), 98.0, 96.0, 101.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:35:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:35:59'), 100.0, 93.0, 105.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:36:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:36:59'), 103.0, 101.0, 108.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:37:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:37:59'), 105.0, 101.0, 111.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:38:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:38:59'), 106.0, 103.0, 114.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:39:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:39:59'), 107.0, 104.0, 109.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:40:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:40:59'), 101.0, 95.0, 109.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:41:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:41:59'), 99.0, 96.0, 103.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:42:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:42:59'), 99.0, 96.0, 105.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:43:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:43:59'), 96.0, 95.0, 98.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:44:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:44:59'), 96.0, 94.0, 99.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:45:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:45:59'), 102.0, 96.0, 110.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:46:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:46:59'), 105.0, 102.0, 109.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:47:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:47:59'), 104.0, 100.0, 108.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:48:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:48:59'), 100.0, 98.0, 103.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:49:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:49:59'), 103.0, 99.0, 110.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:50:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:50:59'), 106.0, 99.0, 111.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:51:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:51:59'), 100.0, 95.0, 104.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:52:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:52:59'), 108.0, 102.0, 113.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:53:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:53:59'), 113.0, 106.0, 116.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:54:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:54:59'), 109.0, 105.0, 113.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:55:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:55:59'), 103.0, 101.0, 110.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:56:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:56:59'), 104.0, 94.0, 109.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:57:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:57:59'), 93.0, 82.0, 107.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:58:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:58:59'), 99.0, 94.0, 104.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:59:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 12:59:59'), 98.0, 92.0, 103.0], [Timestamp('2021-06-25 13:00:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-25 13:00:59'), 98.0, 95.0, 102.0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(test_dat, columns=['Start Time', 'End Time', 'HR', 'Min HR', 'Max HR']).set_index('Start Time')
```

**Edit:** Not that it matters, but the threshold I'm using is 103 BPM. (This is computed from statistical quantities, and not a magic number.)

Comment: How do you want to handle breaks where the sensor was removed? Do we need to consider the missing intervals while counting peaks?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I don't think it should be an issue. I suppose it is possible that the sensor is taken off or put on during a peak. But in that case, if the peak was already 5-minutes long, it will be counted. If not, then it shouldn't be counted—independent of the interruption.

Comment: What if the `heart rate > threshold` for more than `5 min`, should we break that into 5 min intervals? For example lets say HR stays above threshold for 12 mins then in that case should we count 1 streak or 2 `5 min` streaks?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Good question! I'll edit my question to address it specifically. Short answer: more than 5 minutes is still one peak. So a peak is defined as the heart rate going above the threshold for 5-min or more. So, more than 5-min is still the same peak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us do in steps

```py
df = df.asfreq('1T').reset_index()

th = 96
th_mask = df['HR'].gt(th)
streaks = (~th_mask).cumsum() # continuous streaks

peaks = df[th_mask].groupby(streaks)['Start Time']\
                   .agg(start_time='first', streak_count='count')

peaks = peaks.query('streak_count >= 5')  # hr > th for at least 5 min
peaks_freq_per_day = peaks.groupby(peaks['start_time'].dt.date)['streak_count'].count()
```

#### Explanations

- `Reindex` the dataframe on `1 min` frequency in order to account for the rows when there is no sensor data available.
- Create a boolean `th_mask` in order to identify the rows where the heart rate is greater than the given threshold `th`

```
>>> th_mask

0      True
1     False
2      True
3     False
4     False
      ...  
56     True
57    False
58     True
59     True
60     True
Name: HR, Length: 61, dtype: bool
```

- Using `cumsum` on `th_mask` identify the continuous streaks where heart rate stays above threshold `th`

```
>>> streaks

0      0
1      1
2      1
3      2
4      3
      ..
56    15
57    16
58    16
59    16
60    16
Name: HR, Length: 61, dtype: int64
```

- Group the dataframe on the continuous streaks and aggregate `Start Time` using `first` and `count`

```
>>> peaks
            start_time  streak_count
HR                                
0  2021-06-25 12:00:00           1
1  2021-06-25 12:02:00           1
3  2021-06-25 12:05:00           2
6  2021-06-25 12:10:00           6
7  2021-06-25 12:17:00           1
10 2021-06-25 12:21:00           4
11 2021-06-25 12:26:00           2
13 2021-06-25 12:30:00          13
15 2021-06-25 12:45:00          12
16 2021-06-25 12:58:00           3
```

- Filter the `peaks` to select only the rows where the heart rate stays above the threshold for at least `5min`

```
>>> peaks
            start_time  streak_count
HR                                
6  2021-06-25 12:10:00           6
13 2021-06-25 12:30:00          13
15 2021-06-25 12:45:00          12
```

- Now we can identify the frequency of peaks per calendar day by grouping the `peaks` on daily frequency and aggregating using `count`.

```
>>> peaks_freq_per_day

start_time
2021-06-25    3
Name: peak_count, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I'll hack away at this a bit later, but I get the following error:
----> 1 df = data.asfreq('1T').reset_index()
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: I think your initial dataframe contains duplicated values in `index` i.e `Start time`, we have to first remove the duplicates in index then you could try `asfreq`. To remove duplicates you can try `data = data[~data.index.duplicated()]`

Comment: Good catch with the duplicates! An error in the sensor caused some duplication on the first day of use. I have taken care of it in the data sanitizer, and the code runs. I will validate the results and accept your answer. Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes, thank you! Sorry for the delay. I still haven't verified by hand yet, but for I'm confident enough to accept your answer based on your explanation, and my initial sniff test. Thank you again.

Comment: @Timtro No worries! Thanks for accepting the answer. Please feel free to let me know if in case you'll run into any problems and I'll try my best to help you =)